Битрикс кнопки появляются далеко
Кнопка редактировать область появляется в стороне от наведенного элемента, а не рядом. Кто сталкивался с таким подскажите как можно исправить


Меня всегда учили программисты на Битриксе говорят всегда нужно задавать уникальные классы и id элементам. Никогда нельзя задавать стили тегам, иначе админка помрёт. У Битрикса для backend и frontend одни и те же стили используются.

Обведённая область под кнопкой должна охватывать включаемую область. Если этого не происходит, значит скрипт не может правильно определть размеры включаемой области.
Просмотрите код страницы с помощью инструментов разработчика и найдите соответствующий div с id, начинающимся на bx_incl_area_. Проверьте, что с размерами div внутри него. Возможно, у него стоит display=absolute. Или где-то ошибка в структуре документа - например, где-то не хватает закрыващего тега.
